# MAX(Date) is giving empty result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table with exchange rate like below
[image]

And I am using the maxofdate to pick all these values based on currency code. But the query is giving blank.

```
Select USDAMOUNT * dbo.EXCHANGERATEAMT 
from dbo.Amount_monthly   
Left Join dbo.EXCHANGERATE on dbo.Amount_monthly.Currencycode=dbo.EXCHANGERATE.fromcurrencycode
WHERE ValidToDateTime = (Select MAX(ValidToDateTime) from dbo.EXCHANGERATE)
AND dbo.EXCHANGERATE.EXCHANGERATETYPECODE = 'DAY'
```

Using this statement

```
CONVERT(DATE,ValidToDateTime) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-1)
```

instead of subquery is giving me expected result.
Can someone correct this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: subquery is not properly closed -- missing `)`.

Comment: Indeed, your posted sql will not even compile. Ensure you pasted correctly

Comment: There's no point left joining a table if you're immediately going to go and mention it in a where clause; any null rows generated by the left join are lost because they logically cannot be equated to anything (The type code, in your case)

Comment: Those two conditions are completely different. One you are comparing to a reference from today and the other is a value in a table.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? That query wont run on both... Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need two things.  First, the condition for the `max()` needs to match the condition in the outer query.  Second, if you really want a `left join`, then conditions on the second table need to go in the `on` clause.

The resulting query looks like:

```
Select . . .
from dbo.Amount_monthly am Left Join
     dbo.EXCHANGERATE er
     on am.Currencycode = er.fromcurrencycode and
        er.ValidToDateTime = (Select max(er2.ValidToDateTime) 
                              from dbo.EXCHANGERATE er2
                              where er2.EXCHANGERATETYPECODE = 'DAY'
                             ) and
        er.EXCHANGERATETYPECODE = 'DAY';
```

I would write this using window functions, but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing WHERE clause for ValidToDateTime and include it in the JOIN as AND condition

```
SELECT USDAMOUNT * dbo.EXCHANGERATEAMT 
  FROM dbo.Amount_monthly   
  LEFT JOIN dbo.EXCHANGERATE 
    ON dbo.Amount_monthly.Currencycode = dbo.EXCHANGERATE.fromcurrencycode
   AND ValidToDateTime = (SELECT MAX(ValidToDateTime) --remove WHERE clause
                            FROM dbo.EXCHANGERATE)
   AND dbo.EXCHANGERATE.EXCHANGERATETYPECODE = 'DAY';
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your query a bit: as the other folks mentioned you needed to close the parentheses around the MAX(Date) sub-query, and if you reference a LEFT JOINed table in the WHERE clause, it behaves like an INNER JOIN, so I changed to in INNER. You also had "dbo" sprinkled in as a field prefix, but that (the namespace) only prefixes a database, not a field. I added the IS NOT NULL check just to avoid SQL giving the "null values were eliminated" SQL warning. I used the aliases "am" for the first table and "er" for the 2nd, which makes it more readable:

```
SELECT am.USDAMOUNT * er.EXCHANGERATEAMT
FROM dbo.Amount_monthly am
    JOIN dbo.EXCHANGERATE er
        ON am.Currencycode = er.fromcurrencycode
WHERE er.ValidToDateTime = (SELECT MAX(ValidToDateTime) FROM dbo.EXCHANGERATE WHERE ValidToDateTime IS NOT NULL)
    AND er.EXCHANGERATETYPECODE = 'DAY'
```

If you're paranoid like I am, you might also want to make sure the exchange rate is not zero to avoid a divide-by-zero error.